# Change image after onclick on icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm trying to change a image after a onclick into a icon

So for example I've got a div:

```
<div class="nav__btns">
    <i class="uil uil-moon change-theme" id="theme-button"></i>
```

Then I've got a img :

```
<img src="assets/img/foot.png" alt="" id="imgClickAndChange" class="about__img">
```

And I want to change by new image

And this is my js file:

```
/==================== DARK LIGHT THEME ====================/ 
const themeButton = document.getElementById('theme-button')
const darkTheme = 'dark-theme'
const iconTheme = 'uil-sun'

// Previously selected topic (if user selected)
const selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selected-theme')
const selectedIcon = localStorage.getItem('selected-icon')

const getCurrentTheme = () => document.body.classList.contains(darkTheme) ? 'dark' : 'light'
const getCurrentIcon = () => themeButton.classList.contains(iconTheme) ? 'uil-moon' : 'uil-sun'

if (selectedTheme) {
  document.body.classList[selectedTheme === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove'](darkTheme)
  themeButton.classList[selectedIcon === 'uil-moon' ? 'add' : 'remove'](iconTheme)
}

themeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle(darkTheme)
    themeButton.classList.toggle(iconTheme)
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "assets/img/rugby.png" //i'm adding this line but not working
    localStorage.setItem('selected-theme', getCurrentTheme())
    localStorage.setItem('selected-icon', getCurrentIcon())
})
```

I'm adding a specific line but doesn't working, anybody can help me

Comment: `document.getElementById('theme-button')` <-- this won't work if your `<script>` is in your `<head>` without `defer` or otherwise runs before `DOMContentLoaded`. (Also, I really think you should use semicolons, but that's just my opinion)

Comment: `<i>` should not be used represent an interactive element, use a `<button>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `==` a comparison operator, you need `=`

```
document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "assets/img/rugby.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
themeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle(darkTheme)
    themeButton.classList.toggle(iconTheme)
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "assets/img/rugby.png" // You have to assign it , you have to only use single equals to sign
    localStorage.setItem('selected-theme', getCurrentTheme())
    localStorage.setItem('selected-icon', getCurrentIcon())
})
```